# do not conneting to mongodb in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, server

**while writing code for connecting mongodb through node in a project it shows error**

**i used the below code for connecting to mongodb**

```
var mongocilent=require('mongodb').mongocilent
var state = {db:null}
module.exports.connect=function(done){
var url ='mongodb://localhost:27017'
var dbname = "shopping" 
mongocilent.connect(url,(err,data)=>{
    if(err)return done(err)
        state.db=data.db(dbname)
        done()
    
})
module.exports.get=function(){
return state.db
```

}

**but if i start the server it shows:**

```
npm start
> shopping-cart@0.0.0 start
> nodemon ./bin/www

[nodemon] 2.0.19
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
/home/shinoy/Desktop/binoy/shopping cart/config/connection.js:8
mongocilent.connect(url,(err,data)=>{

            ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect')
at module.exports.connect (/home/shinoy/Desktop/binoy/shopping 
cart/config/connection.js:8:17)

at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shinoy/Desktop/binoy/shopping cart/app.js:10:4)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shinoy/Desktop/binoy/shopping cart/bin/www:7:11)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)

Node.js v18.7.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**i m tried different solution from google but its not work for me**

Answer (score 0):

You spelled it wrong in the first line  on requiring the MongoClient object from mongodb. just replace the first line with this

```
const mongoclient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
```